# Enter-PSSession Id with credentials

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to enter a specific session on a remote machine which has credentials.
I have already setup trusted hosts etc.. and have successfully run commands on new virtual sessions.

I would like to enter the session by providing a session ID.

I have seen documentation for each seperate ways but I'm not sure how to combine them, can someone help?
This is what I would imagine it would look like

```
$username = "exampleUsername"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "examplePassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList($username, $password)
$serverNameOrIp = "exampleIp"
$sessionId = 2

Enter-PSSession -Id $sessionId -ComputerName $serverNameOrIp -Credential $cred
```

However I'm getting very clear invalid argument exceptions which makes sense since the documentation doesn't say anything about this combination:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7

Is there a way to do this? I may be missing something obvious or looking in the wrong place. Many thanks in advance

(for more info)

EDIT:

I am trying to connect to the current interactive user session and run some commands for the user to see. The user is permanently logged in/already logged in and I have their session ID. I just need to use it and connect to it however there are still credentials to use for the machine - I'm unsure how to combine these two.

Comment: The session `Id` value is automatically assigned when the session is created. Though, you have control over the friendly name of the session using the `-Name` parameter. If you know the session `Id` already, its parameter set only includes itself. So you cannot use `-Credential` and `-ComputerName` with it.

Comment: What is the ultimately goal? Is it to use different credentials in an already established session? If you want to authenticate differently, you will need to make a new session as far as I can tell.

Comment: Name approach could be a way to go thanks, I'll give that some investigation.

I am trying to connect to the current interactive user session and run some commands for the user to see. The user is permanently logged in/already logged in.